# Interview challenge about biscuit boxes

Tags: algorithm

I have the following algo/interview question:

> Say I need to prepare n biscuit box, each contains specific number of biscuits that meet specific calorie range. say
>
> ```
> box1: 100 biscuits, calorie 200-300
> box2: 200 biscuits, calorie 190-250
> box3: 100 biscuits, calorie 280-220
> ```
>
> The available biscuits are:
>
> ```
> 50 biscuits with calorie 200
> 250 biscuits with calorie 230
> 100 biscuits with calorie 190
> ```
>
> find a way to prepare all biscuit box or prove there is no solution.

Thought for a while but did not find a good solution. Greedy algorithm does not seem to work here, any hints?

Comment: Not an algorithm expert, but is this the bin-packing problem? If so, as far as I recall, the solution is to brute-force search. However perhaps by searching for that phrase, you can get some better hints.

Comment: It looks like a linear programming problem

Comment: @symcbean Yes, it can be reduced to a maximum flow search, which is a linear programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Greedy algorithm

I think you can do this with a greedy algorithm as follows:

1. Sort your boxes into increasing order of upper limit
2. Sort your biscuits into increasing order of calorie value
3. For each biscuit, place into first empty box that it can fit into

### Example

So for your example, the sorted order (by upper limit):

```
box2: 200 biscuits, calorie 190-250
box3: 100 biscuits, calorie 220-280
box1: 100 biscuits, calorie 200-300
```

and biscuits:

```
100 biscuits with calorie 190
50 biscuits with calorie 200
250 biscuits with calorie 230
```

then place

```
100 calorie 190 biscuits into box2
50 calorie 200 biscuits into box2
50 calorie 230 biscuits into box2 (only 50 because box2 becomes full)
100 calorie 230 biscuits into box3 (only 100 because box3 becomes full)
100 calorie 230 biscuits into box1
```

### Sketch of proof

Suppose all biscuits with calories less than W have been placed into boxes in an optimum way.

Then consider biscuits with calories equal to W.  If there is a choice of box for this weight, then choosing the box with the smallest upper limit can never stop us from placing the remaining biscuits.

Comment: hmm, this seems to be working, I actually ruled out this solution due to a test case I had, I guess I did not calculate right manually at that time.

Comment: `150 biscuits into box 1` is incorrect. Box 1 only require 100 biscuits.

Comment: Counter example: Given box 1: 100 biscuits, calorie 100 - 200 box 2: 100 biscuits, calorie 150-175 and biscuits 100 biscuits @ 100 calories and 100 biscuits @ 200 calories. The optimal solution is to evenly split the biscuits across the boxes, but your algorithm would put all the 100 calorie biscuits into box 1.

Comment: @AndyG: I think we only disagree owing to a different interpretation of the problem.  My understanding is that for your example you would not be allowed to put any biscuits into box 2.  My understanding is that you are only allowed to put a biscuit into box 2 if the number of calories (for that biscuit) is between 150 and 175.  I guess your understanding is that a box is okay if the _average_ number of calories is in the given range.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz: Indeed. Given that it is an interview question where it's not likely anybody would be expected to hand-solve a linear program on account of too much time involved, your interpretation is the likelier.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be reduced to a maximum flow search.

Let's construct a bipartite graph: the first set of vertices will correspond to biscuits(one vertex for each biscuit). The second set corresponds to boxes in the same manner. There is an edge with an infinite capacity between a vertex from the first set and a vertex from the second if a biscuit has appropriate calorie value. There is an edge between the source and each vertex from the first set with a capacity equal to the number of such biscuits. There is also an edge between each vertex from the second set and the sink with a capacity equal to the size of the box.

After that one can just find the maximum flow between the source and the sink and check if all boxes are full.

This solution has polynomial time and space complexity.

Answer (score -2):

Do you need an algorithm for this?

If not, just put the 100 biscuits with calorie 190 into box 2, the 50 biscuits with calorie 200 into box 1, and divide the 250 biscuits with calorie 230 into box 2 and 3.

Comment: yes, the simple data is just for demo. what if you have 100 boxes. just like we can easily sort 1,2,3, but how about 10000 intergers :-)